# Using Theme Customizer Built-In Sections

Tags: theme-customizer

[The WordPress Theme Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) indicates that there are a number of existing pre-built customizer sections available for the theme developer.

> If you want to use any of the existing, built-in ones, you don't need to declare them with add_section(). **Instead, refer to them by name.** The following sections are built-in:
>
> - title_tagline
> - colors
> - header_image
> - background_image
> - nav
> - static_front_page

Refer to them by name?  Huh, what does that even mean?  To understand this more, I created the simplest theme on the planet. Here's my style.css:

```
/*  
Theme Name: Minimal ZZ Test Theme
Author: zipzit
Description: An absolute minimal theme, intended to test Theme Customization API
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags:
Text Domain: zz-test-theme
*/
body{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and index.php:

```
<?php   ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Simple Web Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> this is a test </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the entire theme.  There is no functions.php file.

When I went to the wp-admin panel, Appearance --> Customize I get the following TWO (out of six possible) sections displayed:[image]

How does one "refer" to the section by "name"?  What pulls the canned choices into the wp-admin customize panel?  And my real question is: how can you hide a pre-existing choice when overriding a theme (with a child theme.)  We definitely don't want our future admins the chance to change things they shouldn't be.  (Yes, I know we can utilize the admin permission system to hide elements, but that's not my question...)

Anybody been here before?  Many thx.

Edit/update:

Here's my exact situation.  I do lots of websites, often using a child theme to modify an existing theme that gets me sorta close.  I'm looking for a very simple, non-bloated bootstrap theme.  I found devdmbootstrap3 which I'm pretty impressed with. The only problem is that theme generates a bunch of customization selections that we don't want to display (colors, header image, background image).  I can't figure out what populates those elements. There is no add_section() calls in the functions.php file.  I've been thru that file (and the entire theme, including theme-options.php) pretty carefully.  Again, I think my issue is not understanding the words "refer to them by name".  I just don't see where those items are called.

Hmm.. as I think about this, I can certainly install wordpress core and that template inside a localhost server, then step thru the code debugger style to find what call actually creates those elements.  Ugh.

Any other ideas?  Again, thx.

Comment: The other 4 features rely on your theme [declaring support for them](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) in your `functions.php`, hence why they're not currently visible. Check out [this article for a little more information](http://wptheming.com/2012/06/add-options-to-theme-customizer-default-sections/), the first comment also tips at how to remove them.

Comment: Nope. That's exactly where I started.  I will edit my original question with more specifics.  I can't figure out where those elements are being 'called' into existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default controls are registered in [`WP_Customize_Manager::register_controls()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L1175), which is hooked to `customize_register`. This action is fired in another method, [`wp_loaded()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L406), which is hooked to the action of the same name.

To remove these default controls, use your own handler on `customize_register` with a later priority, so that it runs after `register_controls()` has added them:

```
function wpse_185386_remove_customize_controls( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->remove_section( 'title_tagline' );
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse_185386_remove_customize_controls', 50 /* Priority */ );
```

Comment: Wow.  Let me play around a bit.  I'm curious, what the wpse_big#_ prefix for?  Is that how many custom functions you've created in support of this site?   Oh, and thank you!

Comment: Haha, luckily not. If I'd created ~200k snippets for this site I'd be questioning my sanity. It's the ID of the question (check the URL), and it's a syntax that many authors here adopt (the idea being that there's always some reference back to the question if you find the code unedited in the wild).

Comment: It also saves a lot of headache with copy-pasters who just dump it right in their project - if we start handing out code like `generic_function_name` it won't be long before they hit a redefine/namespace clash.

Comment: Way cool.  In fact, I can certainly use that technique when I find a reference to a function from this site (or any other), and use that function from within my own code.  I've been using comments to describe 'assists' with complete url.  I'm glad I asked.  Is that technique listed as a best practice anywhere?

Comment: I would suggest you keep doing the comment method, and keep all your functions "namespaced" with your own unique project prefix. Like I say, we do it as a "failsafe" for people that won't bother - it's always better to have code consistency in your project. Here's [the relevant discussion on meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/prefixing-function-names).